# How to fix 'You tried to execute a query that does not include X as an aggregate function'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'Customers' in my database that includes the following:

```
CustomerID | SupplierID
```

Each customer is inserted to the database with a supplier , meaning a specific customer could be listed more than once.

I have a specific customer who has CustomerID=X

I'm trying to write a query in SQL that returns a table of the customers who satisfy the equation: number of mutual suppliers between the user and X > 80% of number of suppliers of customer X.

I succeeded to get a table of :

```
CustomerID1 | CustomerID2 | Num of Mutual Suppliers
```

where CustomerID1=X in all rows , but I couldn't include number of suppliers that customer X has in order to select only those who satisfy the condition.

```
select user1
     , user2
     , num_in_common
     , COUNT(*)
  from (select f1.CustomerID as user1, f2.CustomerID as user2, count(*) as num_in_common
from Customers f1 inner join
     Customers f2
     on f1.SupplierID = f2.SupplierID
group by f1.CustomerID, f2.CustomerID)
where user1 = X;
```

I expected to receive a table as following:

```
CustomerID1 | CustomerID2 | Num of Mutual Suppliers | Num of X's Suppliers
```

but I got the error 'You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'user1' as part of an aggregate function'.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired results.  I don't understand what the numerator and denominator is for the 80%.

Comment: I understand it seems a bit weird, but I have a relation that goes like this:
a customer_x is mutual with customer_y if they share at least 80% of the suppliers .
The following equation achieves what I'm looking for:
the number of mutual suppliers >= 80% of the suppliers for customer X

Comment: . . That is how I interpreted the question.

Comment: Wait...MySQL does not raise such an error message in title. That is an MS Access error. Please advise which DBMS you are actually using: only MySQL, only MS Access, or linking MySQL tables inside MS Access GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the previous answer was correct, so I'm just providing a more accurate answer, now that the OP has clarified the question.

```
select x.customerid, c.customerid,
       (count(*) / num_x) as ratio
from customers c cross join
     (select @X as customerid, count(*) as num_x
      from customers c
      where c.customerid = @X
     ) x
where exists (select 1
              from customers cx
              where cx.supplierid = c.supplierid and
                    cx.customerid = @X
             )
group by c.customerid, x.num_x
having count(*) / x.num_x >= 0.8
order by ratio desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d6031b6655c8eaa31924da3745227c3) is a demonstration (without data) that the code is syntactically correct.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4421d5cb0bce84dcae413fc5b376075e) is a demonstration that is works on mock data.

Comment: I appreciate it a lot , but still get an error : An unspecified error occured

Comment: @Basilm . . . Have you defined `@X`?

Comment: OP might not be fully using MySQL. Error message in title is an MS Access message.

Answer (score 0):

With a self join of the table and then `group by` to aggregate:

```
select 
  c.customerid CustomerID1, 
  m.customerid CustomerID2, 
  count(*) num_in_common,
  (select count(*) from customers where customerid = c.customerid) totalofX
from customers c inner join customers m
on m.customerid <> c.customerid and m.supplierid = c.supplierid 
where c.customerid = X 
group by c.customerid, m.customerid
having num_in_common > 0.8 * totalofX
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bmLJD9M4JsebHbTjDiZERT/2).